# How can a dhcp client in linux can send the dhcp option 60 - specifying the vendor-id?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-option

I am using fedora core machine. My linux- fedora core machine - client wants to send the dhcp option 60 specifying the vendor id to the dhcp server. Next, I want to read the dhcp option 43 send by the server. Already, I know that the dhcp server is configured properly. How can I do so? I tried doing google, but majority of the articles are on the server side configuration.

Answer (score 2):

[`man dhclient`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient)

> **`-V`**`<vendor-class-identifier>`
>   Specify the vendor-class-identifier option to send to the DHCP server.

Or alternatively set the option `vendor option space "name";` in the [`dhclient.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf) configuration file:

> The vendor option space statement is used to specify which option space should be used for decoding the vendor-encapsulate-options option if one is received. The dhcp-vendor-identifier can be used to request a specific class of vendor options from the server. See dhcp-options(5) for details.